# MySQL: Combine multiple related tables based on data in multiple rows

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, row, podscms

[UPDATED]

I have **three tables** that are defined by one table and the relationship between those three tables are defined by another table like below:

1. Table #1: **wp_pods_cities** [Cities PODS]

   ```
   item_id  city
   -------- ----------
   1        Albany
   2        Perth
   3        Albany
   4        Hollywood
   5        Albany
   6        San Diego
   7        Denpasar
   ```
2. Table #2: **wp_pods_regions** [Regions PODS]

   ```
   item_id  region
   -------- ------------------
   1        Western Australia
   2        California
   3        Texas
   4        Bali
   ```
3. Table #3: **wp_pods_countries** [Countries PODS]

   ```
   item_id  country
   -------- --------------
   1        Australia
   2        United States
   3        Indonesia
   ```
4. Table #4: **wp_posts** [Post Types]

   ```
   pod_id  pod_name   post_type
   ------- ---------- ----------
   pod_1   countries  pods
   pod_2   regions    pods
   pod_3   cities     pods
   ```
5. Table #5: **wp_podsrel** [PODS Relationship]

   ```
   rel_id  pod_id  item_id  related_pod_id  related_item_id
   ------- ------- -------- --------------- ----------------
   1       pod_2   1        pod_1           1 
   2       pod_2   2        pod_1           2 
   3       pod_2   3        pod_1           2 
   4       pod_2   4        pod_1           3 
   5       pod_3   1        pod_2           1 
   6       pod_3   2        pod_2           1 
   7       pod_3   3        pod_2           2 
   8       pod_3   4        pod_2           2 
   9       pod_3   5        pod_2           3 
   10      pod_3   6        pod_2           3
   11      pod_3   7        pod_2           4
   ```

> NOTE: The tables above are created in **Wordpress** by [PODS CMS
>   plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/pods/) but are **simplified** to make them readable here. The
>   actual tables also have **thousands** of data.

### What I'd Like To Do

I would like to list **the same cities** which are defined (in this case, *Albany*) as well as **the regions** and thus **the countries** they belong to.

- **expected result:**

  ```
  city    region             country
  ------- ------------------ --------------
  Albany  Western Australia  Australia
  Albany  California         United States
  Albany  Texas              United States
  ```

### What I've Tried

```
SELECT ct.city, rg.region, ctr.country
FROM wp_pods_cities AS ct
INNER JOIN wp_podsrel AS rel ON ct.item_id = rel.item_id
AND rel.pod_id IN ('pod_3', 'pod_2')
INNER JOIN wp_pods_regions AS rg ON rel.related_item_id = rg.item_id
INNER JOIN wp_pods_countries AS ctr ON rel.related_item_id = ctr.item_id
WHERE ct.city = 'Albany'
ORDER BY ct.city
```

This will get me the **cities** and their related **regions** but the **countries** aren't related. How do I achieve the sample result above?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to **@sjdaws**'s input I managed to modify **his solution** for my **updated** question.

```
SELECT ct.city, rg.region, co.country
    FROM wp_pods_cities AS ct, wp_podsrel AS pr
        INNER JOIN wp_pods_regions AS rg
            ON rg.item_id = pr.related_item_id
        INNER JOIN wp_podsrel AS pr2
            ON pr2.item_id = rg.item_id
        INNER JOIN wp_pods_countries AS co
            ON co.item_id = pr2.related_item_id
    WHERE ct.city = 'Albany'
        AND pr.item_id = ct.item_id
        AND pr.pod_id = 'pod_3'
        AND pr2.item_id = rg.item_id
        AND pr2.pod_id = 'pod_2'
    ORDER BY co.country, rg.region
```

Check out the result here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d40c0/10

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get the correct output by using the podsrel table twice, once for city, once for region.

```
SELECT ct.city, rg.region, co.country

FROM wp_pods_cities AS ct, wp_podsrel AS pr

INNER JOIN wp_pods_regions AS rg
    ON rg.item_id = pr.related_item_id

INNER JOIN wp_podsrel AS pr2
    ON pr2.item_id = rg.item_id

INNER JOIN wp_pods_countries AS co
    ON co.item_id = pr2.related_item_id

WHERE ct.city = 'Albany'
    AND pr.item_id = ct.item_id

ORDER BY ct.city
```

Comment: Hmmm... The code works for the **sample tables above**, but when I tried it on my **actual database**, it returned more amount of the same cities, some have the right region/country relationship, some others don't. I'm not really sure why. Still checking... Thanks for the reply, though.

Comment: I'm really sorry. It's my fault. I actually tried to modify the `item_id` columns so that they would be readable and recognizable by making them **unique**. But this seems to give the wrong implications that had lead to a different solution. Sorry about that. The `item_id`'s should not have any **prefix**. I will update the question.

Comment: With the **updated** question, the code above resulted like **[this](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d40c0/1)**. Anyway to improve this solution? I can see it's heading in the right direction. Cheers!